# How do i solve this java code having issue with it array issue i want display all the array on system out?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, int, factorial

```
/*WAP in java to store factorial of first five natural numbers and display.*/


public class ArrayFactorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(" factorial of first five natural numbers");
        int fact[] = new int[5];
        int r = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            r = r * i;
            fact[i - 1] = r;
            System.out.println(fact[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display all 5 array how do I show in in display out 
when I am showing display array it show 0 only 
when I display `r` it show properly

Comment: Your questions is not clear. What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: You set `fact[i-1]`, but you display `fact[i]`...

Answer (score 3):

change :

```
System.out.println(fact[i]);
```

By :

```
System.out.println(fact[i-1]);
```

Cause you dont call the good index

Answer (score 2):

You are asigning the value on `fact[i-1]` and then printing `fact[i]` which is `0` yet. So replace `System.out.println(fact[i]);` with `System.out.println(fact[i-1]);`

Answer (score 2):

Try to store index in a separate variable and use it to access the array element for assignment and value

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  int index = i-1;
  r = r * i;
  fact[index] = r;
  System.out.println(fact[index]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    /*WAP in java to store factorial of first five natural numbers and display.*/



public class ArrayFactorial {
public static void main (String [] args ){
    System.out.println(" factorial of first five natural numbers");
    int fact[]  = new int [5];
    int r = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i<=5 ; i++){
        r=r*i;
        fact[i-1]=r;


    }
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ ){
        System.out.println(fact[i]);
    }


}
}
```

this is the answer guys i got it

Comment: No. It looks like you didn't get it actually.

Comment: @juan carlos Mendoza
you can check only
check first that write anything

Comment: What you did here will work (inefficiently), but demonstrates that you didn't understand what the real problem was.We were trying to explain that problem is what [@Dukeling commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343451/how-do-i-solve-this-java-code-having-issue-with-it-array-issue-i-want-display-al#comment83672473_48343451). Here you are creating another for loop to print the values but it would have been a lot easier if you have tried our suggestions. At least go and try them and give the [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to the ones who answered right.